# Nautilus uses natural scrolling, while everything else doesn't

Tags: nautilus, touchpad, scrolling

I've chosen to use old-fashioned "reverse" scrolling, i.e., pulling downwards on your touchpad gets you further down in the document. This works everywhere in Ubuntu, except for in Nautilus and in the software update dialogue (what I've seen so far), which use "natural" scrolling. I would like to use "reverse" scrolling system-wide. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Thinkpad T430s.

Comment: In Mouse&Touchpad, "Natural Scrolling" is enabled, which causes the behaviour mentioned above. If I disable Natural scrolling, I get natural scrolling everywhere... (which is not what I want)

Comment: Johan (welcome on Ask Ubuntu!), you should put your solution as an answer to your own question, so that other users may find it quicker. And so I can upvote your contribution! ;-)

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  I have "natural scrolling" system-wide, but Nautilus is the one exception.

Comment: I had the same problem. @Garrett jolindbe's solution below works for that too. Just make sure natural scrolling is turned on (instead of off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to do the trick: Turn off "Natural Scrolling" in Mouse&Touchpad, then edit the file ~/.Xmodmap to contain "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12". Save, logout, done.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 15 9550. But it's complete magic to me. Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: Umm... this was now 2.5 years ago. I think I found it in some forum somewhere, I have no clue why it works.